# In :before of div need to apply height of image?

Tags: html, css

I have created one div and I need to set the background image of the div. For that I have written the following CSS:

```
div#review:before {
    background: url(review-background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1400px;
    top: -25%;
}
```

But, Here My content is dynamic. So, I can't set the height in CSS. So, Anyone helps me for this without using height?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why have you used pseudo class for setting the background image? You can set it on div too and keep background-size:contain/cover/100%

Comment: @KK , I need to overlap background image on the above div from current div.

Comment: @Mr Lister, "my content",  means whatever is in the div is dynamic content.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Can you post the HTML as well? By the way, your CSS is missing a `content` property.

Comment: From the content property. I can't set the background image as per my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code

remove `position: absolute;height: 1400px;top: -25%;` and add `background-size: cover;` also remove `psuedo` element `:before` its not required

```css
div#review {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  color:yellow;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="review">asdsadsad</div><br>
<div id="review">asdsadsad asasd sdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfdf
</div>

<div id="review">
  <pre>asdsadsad asasd
sdfsdf
sdfsdf
sdfsdfdf</pre>
</div>
```